# Using slickless with shapless records

Tags: scala, slick, shapeless

I've been playing around with [underscoreio/slickless](https://github.com/underscoreio/slickless) trying to use Records instead of HLists. I expected it to work out of the box, since shapeless Records appear to be simple HLists (with tags) but the slickless plugin fails to create a `ProvenShape` from a Record and I wonder why.

I'm intending to use the slick/codegen module to generate table classes like this:

```
class Users( tag: Tag ) extends Table[Record.`'id -> Rep[Long], 'name -> Rep[String], 'age -> Rep[Int]`.T]( tag, "users" ) {
    def id = column[Long]( "id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc )
    def name = column[String]( "name" )
    def age = column[Int]( "age" )

    val row: Record.`'id -> Rep[Long], 'name -> Rep[String], 'age -> Rep[Int]`.T = {
        ( 'id ->> id ) :: ( 'name ->> name ) :: ( 'age ->> age ) :: HNil
    }

    def * : ProvenShape[Record.`'id -> Rep[Long], 'name -> Rep[String], 'age -> Rep[Int]`.T] = ??? // row
}

object Users extends TableQuery( new Users( _ ) )
```

But unfortunately, the `* = row` assignment fails:

```
[error] Users.scala:19: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : shapeless.::[slick.lifted.Rep[Long] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")],slick.lifted.Rep[Long]],shapeless.::[slick.lifted.Rep[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("name")],slick.lifted.Rep[String]],shapeless.::[slick.lifted.Rep[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("email")],slick.lifted.Rep[String]],shapeless.HNil]]]
[error]  required: slick.lifted.ProvenShape[shapeless.::[slick.lifted.Rep[Long] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")],slick.lifted.Rep[Long]],shapeless.::[slick.lifted.Rep[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("name")],slick.lifted.Rep[String]],shapeless.::[slick.lifted.Rep[String] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("email")],slick.lifted.Rep[String]],shapeless.HNil]]]]
[error]     def * : ProvenShape[Record.`'id -> Rep[Long], 'name -> Rep[String], 'email -> Rep[String]`.T] = row
[error]                                                                                                     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (data/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

If it worked I'd be able to strip out columns in an easy and typesafe fashion, which would be a huge gain:

```
case class User( name: String, age: Int )

add( user: User ) = {
    Users.map( _.row - 'id ) += Generic[User].to( user )
}
```